# Rendering a PDF in a Grails Web Flow end state

Tags: pdf, grails, spring-webflow

I am using the Rendering plugin to generate a PDF from within a Web Flow. The problem is that I cannot get my end state to return the PDF response. If I call:

```
renderPdf(template: "/letter/generate/createpdf", model: [letter: flow.letter], filename: 'doc.pdf')
```

From within my end state action, it still tries to return an end state view. I can, however, put this in something like:

```
createpdf {
    action {
        renderPdf(template: "/letter/generate/createpdf", model: [letter: flow.letter], filename: 'doc.pdf')
        return
    }
    on("success").to "finish"
}
```

But then of course I get a:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I basically want my end state to return the PDF file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this functionality works if it's not within the context of a web flow.  I've also noticed that some things don't work quite as I expect on the end state of a web flow.  I'm not clear exactly why that is, but when I've encountered situations like this I have typically resorted to handling it with a redirect to another action.  So essentially just pass your `flow.letter` as a param to another action outside of the webflow; that approach has fixed a number of webflow related problems for me.  Unfortunately I don't have access to my code at the moment, because I seem to recall some nuances around parameters staying in scope when using a redirect at the end of a webflow.  If you run into problems post them here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's exactly the problem I am having now -- getting my Letter object out of the flow